# session Symfony2 not keep values

Tags: symfony

```php
class myController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction($id)
    {
        $session = $this->get('session');

        if(is_null(($session->get('foo')))){
            echo "the variable foo is no set in session";
            $session->set('foo', 'bar');
        }
    }
}
```

Why the msg of the echo appears every time the action is load?

Comment: Can you paste the result of `var_dump($session->isStarted())`? If `false`, try `$session->start()`. If `true`, check your browser settings!

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.0 . This method is only for Symfony 2.1 . I put the $session->start() and check browser settings. In config.yml the session auto_start is true. The msg still appear.

Comment: The problem is I have another object(an entity) which is storing in session either. Don't know why it's interfering in others variables of session. When remove it everything works. Now I have another problem, store entity in session. But I will search more. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```php
class SessionTestController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        $session = $this->get('session');

        if (is_null($session->get('foo'))) {
            $session->set('foo', 'bar');
            $responseText = 'foo is null';
        } else {
            $responseText = 'foo is set';
        }

        // Use a response object
        return new Response($responseText);
    }
}
```